# Open a password protected text file

Tags: c#, text, passwords, zip, protected

Is there anyway to read a Open a password protected text file in C# code.

It is not an encrypted file but a password protected text file.

[image: picture showing where its asking for password]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "password protected?" As far as I know, Windows doesn't have a concept of password protected files. Do you have some sort of add-in for your OS that does password protection?

Comment: I'd be surprised if any Mono-supported OS's have password protection at the FS level as well.

Comment: This is how we receive the files from the third party gives us the files. It is windows.

Comment: Are you maybe talking about the prompt for credentials you get from Windows when accessing a file on a network? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016938/how-to-open-file-by-specific-user. Otherwise, this doesn't sound like a text file, but a file that opens in some application that has password capabilities. How do you open the file manually?

Comment: no I actually am not able to attach a pic as i do not have bonus points. I am not asking about shared drive password. It is actually a windows password. I shall try and upload it somewhere else and add a link

Comment: https://picasaweb.google.com/115996202920892297502/November252013 Check this link for the picture showing where its asking for password

Comment: No its the text file that is encrypted Not the Zip file

Comment: Yes it is a Text SP.text is the name of the text file . I have marked off the rest of the file name in black to avoid displaying full filename on internet. And the "..." is just addition to the message box it seems

Comment: @user1715751 Well, it's the txt file inside the zip archive that's password protected. And that protection is zip-specific.

Comment: Good . I did not find any help online anywhere on password protected text files

Answer (score 4):

I had no trouble reproducing that dialog:

[image]

The dialog styling is a little different, this came from a Windows 8.1 machine.  But it is the exact same one as yours.  It is displayed when you open a .zip archive that's password protected with Windows Explorer.  Which displays the prompt when you double-click a file inside the archive.

You extract files from a .zip archive in your own code with one of the many Zip libraries.  Popular ones are SharpZiplib, DotNetZip and 7-Zip.  They all support extracting files that are password protected, covered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607858/how-to-zip-and-unzip-using-password-in-c-sharp-program).

Comment: It is a poorly documented question, that doesn't make the subject of using a zip library in a .NET program off topic.

Comment: The [c#] tag is a pretty good hint.  Why are you giving me a hard time answering a difficult question?  You can express your displeasure by voting on the question.  Get off my case, please.

Comment: Thanks @hans I shall use the ShareZipLib and yes its .NET application